# Retrieve fields under a certain Custom object using Metadata API/Metadata Service class

Tags: metadata-api, custom-metadata

I have a requirement where we have to retrieve all the fields under an Object say Standard or Custom. I am using FinancialForce Metadata service [class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). I can Retrieve all the Custom objects and all the Custom fields independently but my requirement is to retrieve only the custom fields only under a certain object. Below code logic is used to retrieve custom objects and fields.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
List < MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery > queries = new List < MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery > ();
MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryLayout = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties;
queryLayout.type_x = 'CustomObject';  // 'CustomField'
queries.add(queryLayout);
fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, '36.0');

List < String > fullNames = new List < String > ();
if (fileProperties != null) {
    for (MetadataService.FileProperties fileProperty: fileProperties) {
        fullNames.add(fileProperty.fullName);
    }
}
fullNames.sort();  // List of Custom objects/fields


private static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService() {

    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.endpoint_x = //'Org End point';
    service.timeout_x = 120000; //Setting the time out 
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = // AOauth Access Token
    return service;
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I used [ReadMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_readMetadata.htm) of CRUD based calls to get custom field names of certain custom object. Pass the custom object name to below method to get the list of Field names.

```
public static list < String > readCustomObjectSync(String objectName) {

    //Creating a Service for Callout
    MetadataService.MetadataPort metadataConnection = createService();

    //Checking for namespace
    MetadataService.DescribeMetadataResult describeRes = metadataConnection.describeMetadata('36.0');
    if(describeRes!=null){
        List<MetadataService.DescribeMetadataObject> objectList = describeRes.MetadataObjects;
        String namespace = describeRes.organizationNamespace;

        if(objectName.contains('__c')) {
            if(namespace != null && namespace !='') {
                objectName=namespace+'__'+objectName;
            }
        }
    }

    List <String> objectNames = new List <String>();
    objectNames.add(objectName);

    List <String> fieldName = new List <String>();

    try {
        MetadataService.IReadResult readResult = metadataConnection.readMetadata('CustomObject', objectNames);
        MetadataService.Metadata[] mdInfo = readResult.getRecords();
        System.debug('Number of component info returned: '
                     + mdInfo);
        for (MetadataService.Metadata md : mdInfo) {
            if (md != null) {
                MetadataService.CustomObject obj = (MetadataService.CustomObject) md;
                System.debug('Custom object full name: '+ obj);
                if(obj.fields != null) {
                    for(MetadataService.CustomField field : obj.fields) {
                        if(field != null) {
                            fieldName.add(field.fullName);
                            System.debug('Field Name: ' + field.fullName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.debug('Empty metadata.');
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ce) {
        System.debug('exception ' + ce.getMessage());
    }

    return fieldName;
}
```